# Window Onload Still Holding Up Whole Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I put the following script on my page so that it would load after everything else and wouldn't slow down my page (I have an api call in the append which is why, but I've let it out for this), but it's still loading with the rest of the page.

```
<script>
   $(window).load(function(){
     $('.status').append('result');
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you need help with?

Comment: Making it wait to load these scripts until everything else loads first.

Comment: Load what scripts? Where is the API call? What do you expect `.append('result')` to do?

Comment: `$(window).load` gets called after the complete page is fully loaded including all external resources.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in my comment above, `$(window).load` gets called after all external resources load fully. 
If you want to execute a script before everything loads, you may consider the following

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>alert(1)</script>
</head>


<body></body>

</html>
```